# MySQL IF conditions

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm not too familiar with the if conditions although I have read the resources, here is the statement i'm starting with:

```
$Phone = $MyDB['Phone'];
$Mobile = $MyDB['Mobile'];

"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ((number LIKE '%$Phone%') OR (number LIKE '%$Mobile%))";
```

Now it's possible that either $Phone or $Mobile might be equal to nothing but can't both be equal to nothing, in which case this query will return all data. So I thought I could try:

```
$NoValue = '';

"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE IF('$Phone' != '$NoValue', (number LIKE '%$Phone%'), (number LIKE '%Mobile%'))";
```

Of course this is a very simplified version of what the query actually is, as I need to compare several things to return the correct values, am I allowed to used an if after the WHERE? Does anyone have a working example of correct usage would be very handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
SELECT * , IF('$phone' = '$novalue','%$mobile%','%$phone%') as comparevalue    
FROM TABLE GROUP BY Id_column HAVING number LIKE comparevalue
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're using PHP, so why you no make something like:

```
if(isset($Phone)){
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE number LIKE '%$Phone%'";
}else{
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE number LIKE '%Mobile%'";
}
```

Comment: Because there are so many variables in the actual expression, doing the logic in PHP like that will be too cumbersome and too lengthy

Comment: try check this [IF MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/if-statement.html) You can do something like add the part of the query in PHP, i think in MySQL will be too long too.
Something like
`$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE number LIKE '%Mobile%'";
if(isset($Phone)){
$query .= " AND number LIKE '%$Phone%'";
}
if(isset($var2){
$query .= " AND number LIKE '%$var2%'";
}
...
if(isset($varn){
$query .= " AND number LIKE '%$varn%'";
}`